# C++: Traverse DBUS message to find BlueZ 5 adapter using iterator

Tags: c++, bluetooth, iterator, dbus, bluez

I am trying to find available BlueTooth adapters using the BlueZ 5 updated Dbus API.

Unlike BlueZ 4, which has a method exactly for this (i.e. org.bluez.Manager.FindAdapter()), BlueZ 5 uses the FreeDesktop ObjectManager interface with the method GetManagedObjects().  This method returns a very large array of results:

```
array [
      dict entry(
         object path "/org/bluez"
         array [
            dict entry(
               string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
               array [
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.bluez.AgentManager1"
               array [
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.bluez.ProfileManager1"
               array [
               ]
            )
         ]
      )
      dict entry(
         object path "/org/bluez/hci0"
         array [
            dict entry(
               string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
               array [
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.bluez.Adapter1"
               array [
                  dict entry(
                     string "Address"
                     variant                         string "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Name"
                     variant                         string "My_Adapter"
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Alias"
                     variant                         string "kubuntu-0"
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Class"
                     variant                         uint32 0
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Powered"
                     variant                         boolean false
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Discoverable"
                     variant                         boolean true
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "DiscoverableTimeout"
                     variant                         uint32 0
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Pairable"
                     variant                         boolean true
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "PairableTimeout"
                     variant                         uint32 0
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Discovering"
                     variant                         boolean false
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "UUIDs"
                     variant                         array [
                           string "00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                           string "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                           string "00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                           string "0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                           string "0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                        ]
                  )
                  dict entry(
                     string "Modalias"
                     variant                         string "usb:sdfasdfsadf"
                  )
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
               array [
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.bluez.Media1"
               array [
               ]
            )
            dict entry(
               string "org.bluez.NetworkServer1"
               array [
               ]
            )
         ]
      )
      .
      .etc.
      . ]
```

[The BlueZ 5 API Intro and Porting Guide](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/) says, "*The concept of a default adapter was always a bit fuzzy and the value could’t be changed, so if applications need something like it they could e.g. just pick the first adapter they encounter in the GetManagedObjects reply.*"

I've written C++ code using iterators to do this (I have no experience with Python), but it's really long for something that seems so simple:

```
if (dbus_message_iter_init(reply, &rootIter) && //point iterator to reply message
    DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&rootIter)) //get the type of message that iter points to
{
    debug_print("Type Array.\n");   
    DBusMessageIter arrayElementIter;
    dbus_message_iter_recurse(&rootIter, &arrayElementIter); //assign new iterator to first element of array
    debug_print("-->Descending into Array (recursing).\n");

   while(!adapterFound){
    if (DBUS_TYPE_DICT_ENTRY == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&arrayElementIter))
    {
        debug_print("  Type Dict_Entry.\n");

        DBusMessageIter dictEntryIter;
        dbus_message_iter_recurse(&arrayElementIter,&dictEntryIter ); //assign new iterator to first element of
        debug_print("  -->Descending into Dict_Entry (recursing).\n");
        if (DBUS_TYPE_OBJECT_PATH == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&dictEntryIter))
                {
            debug_print("    Type DBUS_TYPE_OBJECT_PATH.\n");
            dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&dictEntryIter, &adapter_path);  
            if(device && strstr(adapter_path,device)) 
            {   
               adapterFound = TRUE;
               debug_print("    Adapter %s FOUND!\n",device);
            }
        }
        dbus_message_iter_next(&dictEntryIter);
        if (DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&dictEntryIter))
                    {
                            debug_print("    Type DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY.\n");
            DBusMessageIter innerArrayIter;
            dbus_message_iter_recurse(&dictEntryIter, &innerArrayIter);
            dbus_message_iter_next(&innerArrayIter);
            debug_print("    -->Descending into Array (recursing).\n");
            if (DBUS_TYPE_DICT_ENTRY == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&innerArrayIter))
            {
                debug_print("      Type Dict_Entry.\n");
                DBusMessageIter innerDictEntryIter;
                dbus_message_iter_recurse(&innerArrayIter,&innerDictEntryIter ); //assign new iterator to first element of
                debug_print("      -->Descending into Dict_Entry (recursing).\n");
                if (DBUS_TYPE_STRING == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&innerDictEntryIter))
                {
                    debug_print("        Type DBUS_TYPE_STRING.\n");
                    char *dbusObject;
                    dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&innerDictEntryIter, &dbusObject);
                    debug_print("        This is an object of type:%s.\n", dbusObject);
                    if(strncmp(dbusObject,adapterString,strCmpLimit))
                        debug_print("        Not an adapter.\n");
                    else{
                        if(!device)
                        {
                           debug_print("        No adapter given, so using first available: %s\n", adapter_path);
                           adapterFound = TRUE;
                        }
                        debug_print("        Adapter.\n");
                    }
                }
                debug_print("      <--Ascending from Dict_Entry.\n");
            }
            debug_print("    <--Ascending from Array (top layer).\n");
                            //dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&dictEntryIter, &adapter_path);  
                    }

        debug_print("  <--Ascending from Dict_Entry.\n");
    }
    debug_print("<--Ascending from Array (top layer).\n");
    if(!dbus_message_iter_has_next(&arrayElementIter)) break; //check to see if end of array
    else dbus_message_iter_next(&arrayElementIter);

    }//while loop end --used to traverse array
} //end if - outer arrray
else return 0;
```

In other words, I have to define a new iterator for each branch of the tree, just to find a string that is in a fixed location every time. (array[x]->secondfield[2]->firstfieldstring)  My question (finally, I know) is can someone point out a more elegant/faster solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties) interface that should be implemented by the BLuez 5 Adapter object to get the adapter properties.

As far as I know you will still need to traverse the Array till you find the adapter object path, but starting from there, you could do something like:

```
DBusMessage *msg = dbus_message_new_method_call(
        "org.bluez",
        adapter_object_path,
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties", "Get");

const char *property = "Powered"; // (e.g.)
dbus_message_append_args(msg,
        DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &property,
        DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);

//...
```

This way you could just look in the array for adapter object paths, and ignore all the rest. With this object path you can than request the required properties and/or start sending method calls.

I'm not sure if this could be considered more 'elegant', and it will probably not be faster either because I think the additional method calls will be slower than the array traversals.
It should/could reduce the amount of code and make it more readable though...